# jQuery animation in order delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Hey all I am trying to call out animations in order. Currently the code below seems to call them all out at the same time even with the *delay* function (which doesn't seem to be working at all...)

```
$(".overlayChoice1").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-15px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })               
$(".overlayChoice2").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-45px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
$(".overlayChoice3").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-75px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
$(".overlayChoice4").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-105px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
```

What all would I need to do in order to have the execute one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animations to happen sequentially you should nest each animation in the `complete` callback of the prior:

```
$(".overlayChoice1").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-15px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
    $(".overlayChoice2").delay(500).animate({
       top: '-45px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
       $(".overlayChoice3").delay(500).animate({
         top: '-75px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
            $(".overlayChoice4").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-105px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' });
        })
    })
})
```

`.animate` reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You either need to send the next one as a callback, or use incremental delays.

Callbacks:

```
$(".overlayChoice1").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-15px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
    $(".overlayChoice2").delay(500).animate({
        top: '-45px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
        $(".overlayChoice3").delay(500).animate({
            top: '-75px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
            $(".overlayChoice4").delay(500).animate({
                top: '-105px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' }, function(){
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Incremental delays:

```
$(".overlayChoice1").delay(500).animate({
    top: '-15px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })               
$(".overlayChoice2").delay(2700).animate({
    top: '-45px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
$(".overlayChoice3").delay(4900).animate({
    top: '-75px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
$(".overlayChoice4").delay(7100).animate({
    top: '-105px' }, { duration: 1700, easing: 'easeOutElastic' })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(".overlayChoice1").animate({ top: '-15px' }, 1700, "easeOutElastic", function() {
    // Animation overlayChoice1 complete.
    $(".overlayChoice2").animate({ top: '-45px' }, 1700, "easeOutElastic", function() {
      // Animation overlayChoice2 complete.
      .....
    } })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a much more [DRY implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) that doesn't repeat so much code and triggers the next animation based on the completion callback of the previous one:

```
function runAnimations() {
    var cntr = 1, top = -15;
    function next() {
        if (cntr <= 4) {
            $(".overlayChoice" + cntr).delay(500)
              .animate({top:top+'px'}, {duration:1700, easing:'easeOutElastic'}, next);
            ++cntr;
            top -= 30;
        }
    }
    next();
}
```